# Should there be single DbContext and Database within the ASP.NET MVC 5 Web Application to be able associate User's Accounts with objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I am creating webapplication. I created a `class Person` and a `class Meeting` sometimes Person is associated with meeting. So I've done:

```
public class PersonContext : DbContext {

        public PersonContext(): base("PersonContext") { }

        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Status> Statuses { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
```

As we see it makes connection with:
`<add name="PersonContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=WebApplication2;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>`

Everything was great **until I found** out that I need to associate User Accounts with `Meeting`s too.

But User Accounts are held **in other database**:

```
  public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {

        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
```

and it's connection string:

`<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebApplication2-20140711041006.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication2-20140711041006;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

Question: What should I do to be able associate `Meeting` with a User Account. Should I change:

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
                : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
```

to
    public ApplicationDbContext()
                    : base("PersonContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)

or delete `class PersonContext` and move its' all fields to `ApplicationDbContext`?

I have done this:

```
 public class PersonContext : ApplicationDbContext {

        public PersonContext() { }

        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Meeting> Meetings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Status> Statuses { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
```

and after Update-Database I get:

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

    WebApplication2.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
    WebApplication2.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
    IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
    IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should extend the generated `ApplicationDBContext` with your own classes (or your own DBContext should inherit from `ApplicationDBContext`), so that everything is kept in the same database and accessible through the same DB Context.

Don't create another separate context. That will make relations of the kind you describe very hard to achieve.

If you chose to override `OnModelCreating()` in your derived context, you must call the base `OnModelCreating()`, because it is the `IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey, TUserLogin, TUserRole, TUserClaim>.OnModelCreating()` method that sets up all the mapping for the identity classes.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
  modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you I decided to inherit form `ApplicationDbContext`but after migrations I get error, please see EDIT in OP.

Comment: Ok Please don't answer yet. I try to merge `ApplicationDbContext` and `PersonContext` in the code.

Answer (score 1):

I post it as answer but without pointing direction by **Anders Abel** it would be hard to do.

So I deleted `PersonContext` and `PersonInitilizer`. Fields from `PersonContext` moved to `IdentityModels.cs` to class `ApplicationDbContext`.

Contents of seed method were moved to `Configuration.Migrations.Seed(...)` method. Also all references to `PersonContext` were changed to `ApplicationDbContext`.

Then I did: `base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` in OnModelCreating

I also deleted whole block from `Web.config`:

```
 <contexts>
     <context type="WebApplication2.Models.ApplicationDbContext, WebApplication2">
        <databaseInitializer type="WebApplication2.Migrations.Configuration, WebApplication2" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
```

after that you should open Package Manager and type and execute: `update-database` and it should be fine.